# Creating a dictionary iterating items from an html file

Tags: python, html, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an html file with Beautifulsoup.

I want to build a dictionary "item_dict"out of iterating items in a div "section" found under several div tags that have exactly the same structure: products are found within  and so on:

Below is my code:

```
for data in soup.find_all("div", "descr"):

    item_dict= {
        "product": data.find('h4'),
        "brand": data.find('h5'), 
        "price": data.find('price'),
        }

    print item_dict
```

The problem is that with this code I am only able to get the first product on the list but not the rest.

I have tried with data.find_all (but gives me a list of all the products as values) and with data.get (which outputs []).

How could I build my dictionary iterating over all the available items?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get data.find or thereof to work for other items before you place it in the dictionary? I would make sure that works first.

Comment: Everything works fine separately. data.find item outputs the corresponding value and when I test find_all("div", "desc"), without building the dictionary,  it outputs the entire data just fine.

Comment: And you are sure your for loop works fine? ie adding     ''list_1 = soup.find_all("div", "descr")'' and then ''for data in list_1:''  doesn't make a difference?

Comment: After trying several solutions, the code works "better"with soup.find (instead of soup.find_all). The only issue is that, although it builds the correct dictionaries, now it also outputs a first and last dictionary with "None"for value for each key (product, brand, price).

Comment: would limiting the inputs (i.e. for  data in list_1[1:-2] # 2nd to second to last values in the list) solve that problem?